# django filter all in generic foreign keys?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I have 2 tables and a third with a Generic foreign key, essentially joining table one a two.

```
class InternalOffer(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('User')
    (offer data...)
    relation = GenericRelation(OfferJoin, related_query_name='offer')

class ExternalOffer(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('User')
    (offer data...)
    relation = GenericRelation(OfferJoin, related_query_name='offer')

class OfferJoin(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    offer = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

I want to be able to query both External and Internal Offers to display all of them on a single page. I can query all of them with `OfferJoin.objects.all()` but I need to be able to filter by user, something like `OfferJoin.objects.filter(offer__user__id=request.user.id)`

What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks.

**EDIT: Solution**

It turns out, `related_query_name` in `GenericRelation` can not be identical to the name of the `GenericForeignKey` column. Here is the update line:

```
    relation = GenericRelation(OfferJoin, related_query_name='offerquery')
```

This lets me filter properly, but I can't `.exclude()` on the query. It's a step in the right direction though.

Answer (score 0):

How about reversing it?

```
internal = InternalOffer.objects.filter(user=user)
external = ExternalOffer.objects.filter(user=user)
result = [internal, external]
```

And in the template do:

```
{% for subresult in result %}
  {% for offer in subresult %}
    {{ offer.relation }}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```